# DNSMasq resolving not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq

We installed DNSMasq for delivering ip addresses and tft bootinng.

As the service dnsmasq is running , the resolving on the local ubuntu system is not working:
root@dnsmasq001:~# ping joeri001
ping: unknown host joeri001
The /etc/resolv.conf contains:
127.0.0.1

If we stop dnsmasq , the resolving is working.
Any idea why this is happening?

Also the resolving is not working for the devices which got an ip from the dnsmasq dhcp server.
How can I set nameservers and search ?

Kr,

Joeri

Answer (score 0):

1. The local resolving can be fixed by adding `DNSMASQ_EXCEPT=lo` in /etc/defaults/dnsmasq
2. To add name servers / search option to the dnsmasq dhcp server 
   dhcp-option=option:domain-search,joeri.com
   dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.0.105